# Why I can't use the variable in a JAVA method?

Tags: java, android, variables, scope

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Context cx;
    private int pageNumber=0;


    private void populateList() {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams paras = new RequestParams();
        paras.put("page",this.pageNumber+1);
        ............
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener loadMoreButtonOnClick = new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            RequestParams paras = new RequestParams();
            paras.put("page",this.pageNumber+1); //can't resolve symbol "pageNumnber"
            client.get("http://APIAddressHere",paras,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody){
                    //it's ok;
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error)
                {
                    // Response failed :(
                }

            });
        }
    };
}
```

In the second function(loadMoreButtonOnClick), where I have commented, the IDE throws a error which seems that I can't access the variable(private int pageNumber) which I have created there.

But I can access pageNumber in the populateList() function, why I can't access it in the loadMoreButtonOnClick(), is that means that I'm already in a different context?

The System is: JDK 6, Android Studio 0.4.2, my project is from API 9 to API 18

**I'm new to Java. So my Questions are:**
1. Why?
2. How to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That reference is inside your anonymous `Button.OnClickListener` subclass, so `this` refers to the listener, not the activity.

Using simply `pageNumber` rather than `this.pageNumber` should work, as the surrounding scope is still valid. Alternatively, `MainActivity.this.pageNumber` will also work (letting the compiler know you wish to refer to the instance of the outer class).

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer! It works now. I prefer the "MainActivity.this.pageNumber" way due to its specific.

Comment: you can also reffer to : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html#shadowing